# Change destination of git push

Tags: git

I have to remote repositories

```
$ git remote show

repoA
origin
```

`git push` will push changes to **origin**, how can I change the push destination so that it goes to repoA's url? I know I could use `git push repoA branch` but I want to just push to repoA master for now.

Comment: For more details than the answers below, type `git help push`.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to push just for now, you can run this command:

```
git push <REMOTENAME> <BRANCHNAME>
```

If your remote branch has different name than your local branch, you can run like this:

```
git push <remote-name> <local-name:remote-name>
```

If you want to set as default upstream git push behavior you can do like this:

```
git push -u <remote name> <local name>
```

or checkout to local branch and run:

```
git branch --set-upstream-to <remote-name>
```

and every time you run git push and gonna push to the repository you set

To validate the branch is setup with the correct upstream remote:

```
git branch -vv
```

Answer (score 1):

use the below command,

```
git push repoA master
```

basically, it is

```
git push <remote_name> <branch_name>
```

Specifying the branch name as master will get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

> I know I could use git push repoA branch but I want to just push to repoA master for now.

`master` is a branch. There is nothing special about `master` other than it is the default name of the initial branch created by `git init`.

Answer (score 0):

it is also possible to change destination branch directly on GitHub
click `edit` button, on top at the right side of your PR name. then you will have the option to select the right destination branch.